# Turning a number that appears to be a string, and making it an integer?

Tags: php, string, variables, integer

I have looked through numerous threads, alas & alac, no joy in finding a straight forward way of making a string (brought in from javascript) into use as a php variable.

I have it as a variable, but if you echo a simple mathematical formula then it is if it has no value, i.e.

my dubious variable is $fig,

```
 echo $fig;
 prints e.g. 15
```

however,

```
 $tester = 2;
 $sum = $fig + $tester;
 echo $sum;
```

gives me 2 !!!

I´ve tried so many options now I'm wondering if I am right to say this is a string or maybe its a server-side variable that is unusable as an integer??

This is a simple logical code, that has me chasing my tail for an answer.

Comment: please post actual code

Comment: If $fig is a string and you try to use the `+` operator with it, PHP will coerce it into a number and $sum will contain 17.  So something else is going on.

Comment: Tried everything, I arrived at it after struggling like many to get the anchor value after the hash. All looked sweet, then I discovered the variable was unusable to query other data from mysql. Thanks, I'm also bewildered.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, clearly I'm a newbie. Ta.

Comment: I have even tried multiplying the variable by 1, still no joy. I felt like I was in the Twilight Zone, too many laate hours with sore eyes trying to finish my project website. Any ideas James?

Comment: "anchor value after the hash"? url anchors are NOT sent to the server.

Comment: Do `var_dump($fig)` and update your question with the result because clearly it is not being coerced to an integer.

Comment: Hi Marc, I read that url anchors were not sent to the server, but I was hoping to then use the formed variable to then, after a captcha box, do a query in mysql. If that makes sense. It gives me a value, though it appears to be an empty value even though it echos with an integer. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your input is, so have you tried casting as an integer?

e.g.

```
$fig = (int) $fig;
echo $fig; // 15
$tester = 2;
$sum = $fig + $tester;
echo $sum;  // 17
```

Comment: Tried it, nope. I used where $hash was 18:                                                             <?php
    $mash = (int) $hash;
    echo $hash;
    echo $mash;
    $check = 3;
    $third = $check + $mash;
?>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
    print ($third);

    ?>

Comment: need to master adding comments apparently too

Comment: Haha, so what was the output for hash, mash and third?

Comment: Sorry, every time I try to go to a new line it posts my edit. Gremlins at work.

Comment: That is really odd! One more thing: before you cast as int can you do: gettype($hash) to find out what php thinks it is.

Comment: Using:                                                                                         <?php

$data = array(1, 1., NULL, new stdClass, 'foo');

foreach ($data as $hash) {
    echo gettype($hash), "\n";
}


?>   I get "foo" instead of the 18. So I guess since each represents: integer
double
NULL
object
string, then my variable is a numeric string, not an integer.